# Flutter: Should I use Bloc, or should I use redux?

Tags: flutter, redux, bloc

Hello I am new to flutter and is intertwined if I should use Bloc for State Management or redux. I am having a restaurant POS app where I state management is a must. I have a good experience with redux but Bloc has been recommended for flutter.

My Question is:

1.) Should I switch to Bloc or remain using redux where I am comfortable?

2.) What would be the pros and cooons of the two?

3.) Which of the are more scalable and mantainable?

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used both redux and bloc and I think that bloc is much better. You don't have to write reducers, actions etc. So your code is smaller and clear.

If you wanna try use provider its great.

Official link at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro  and   https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options gives a detailed view.

Comment: Okaay thank you, we're about to use redux but yes I think the links you provided are excellent thanks a lot! Do you know what code structure would work best for Bloc?